# Python AttributeError: 'FSM' object has no attribute 'AddState'

Tags: python, python-2.7, artificial-intelligence, state-machine, fsm

I am trying to create a very basic Finite State Machine in Python and keep getting the following error/s:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\RobotMaid_FSM.py", line 143, in <module>
r = RobotMaid()
File "C:\Python27\RobotMaid_FSM.py", line 129, in __init__
self.FSM.AddState("Sleep", Sleep(self.FSM))
AttributeError: 'FSM' object has no attribute 'AddState'
```

I've tried many suggestions I've read from here and other places and searched for a long time for a solution but nothing seems to work, and I know it's probably some simple piece of code I haven't included or haven't implemented properly. My code is as follows:

```
from random import randint
from time import clock



class Transition(object):
def __init__(self, toState):
    self.toState = toState

    def Execute(self):
        print "Transitioning..."



class State(object):
def __init__(self, FSM):
    self.FSM = FSM
    self.timer = 0
    self.startTime = 0

    def Enter(self):
        self.timer = randint(0, 5)
        self.startTime = int(clock())
        def Execute (self):
            pass
        def Exit(self):
            pass

class CleanDishes(State):
def __init__(self, FSM):
    super(CleanDishes, self).__init__(FSM)

    def Enter(self):
        print "Preparing to clean dishes."
        super(CleanDishes, self).Enter()

        def Execute (self):
            print "Cleaning dishes"
            if (self.startTime + self.timer <= clock()):
                if not (randint(1, 3) %2):
                    self.FSM.ToTransition
                else:
                        self.FSM.ToTransition

                        def Exit(self):
                            print "Finished cleaning dishes."

class Vacuum(State):
           def __init__(self, FSM):
                super(Vacuum, self).__init__(FSM)

           def Enter(self):
                         print "Starting to Vacuum"
                         super(Vacuum, self).Enter()

           def Execute(self):
                         print "Vacuuming"
                         if (self.startTime + self.timer <= clock()):
                                       if not (randint(1, 3) %2):

self.FSM.ToTransition("toSleep")
                                       else:

self.FSM.ToTransition("toCleanDishes")

           def Exit(self):
                          print "Finished Vacuuming"

class Sleep(State):
def __init__(self, FSM):
    super(Sleep, self).__init__(FSM)
    self.sleepAmount = 0
    self.startTime = 0

    def Enter(self):
                  print "Starting to Sleep"
                  super(Sleep, self).Enter()

    def Execute(self):
        print "Sleeping"
        if (self.startTime + self.timer <= clock()):
            if not (randint(1, 3) %2):
                          self.FSM.ToTransition("toVacuum")
            else:
                          self.FSM.ToTransition("toCleanDishes")

            def Exit(self):
                        print "Waking up from Sleep"



class FSM(object):
def __init__(self, character):
    self.char = character
    self.states = {}
    self.transitions = {}
    self.curState = None
    self.prevState = None
    self.trans = None

    def AddTransition(self, transName, transition):
        self.transitions[transName] = transition

        def AddState(self, stateName, state):
            self.states[stateName] = state

            def SetState(self, stateName):
                self.prevState = self.curState
                self.curState = self.states[stateName]

                def ToTransition(self, toTrans):
                    self.trans = self.transitions[toTrans]

                    def Execute(self):
                        if (self.trans):
                            self.curState.Exit()
                            self.trans.Execute()
                            self.SetState(self.trans.toState)
                            self.curState.Enter()
                            self.trans = None
                            self.curState.Execute()


Char = type("Char", (object,), {})

class RobotMaid(Char):
def __init__(self):
    self.FSM = FSM(self)

    self.FSM.AddState("Sleep", Sleep(self.FSM))
    self.FSM.AddState("CleanDishes", CleanDishes(self.FSM))
    self.FSM.AddState("Vacuum", Vacuum(self.FSM))

    self.FSM.AddTransition("toSleep", Transition("Sleep"))
    self.FSM.AddTransition("toVacuum", Transition("Vacuum"))
    self.FSM.AddTransition("toCleanDishes", Transition("CleanDishes"))

    self.FSM.SetState("Sleep")

def Execute(self):
             self.FSM.Execute()

if __name__=='__main__':
          r = RobotMaid()
          for i in xrange(10):
                        startTime - clock()
                        timeInterval = 1
                        while (startTime + timeInterval > clock()):
                                     pass
                        r.Execute()
```

Comment: Check the indentation of the `FSM` class, it looks like you have nested functions there.  For example, `AddState()` is declared and scoped within `AddTransition()`.  As posted, the indentation on all the other classes is incorrect as well, but that can be a result of copy and paste.

Comment: Thank you, you are right and now the error has been fixed! The program now is not producing any errors, but it's still not working either. I'll keep trying to fix it, but you helped a lot with fixing that error, so thank you!